# order by list of names and then the rest of the data

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a table with column name.
I want to order it by a list of names and then other by the rest of column.

for example this is the list:

```
RAM
DPR
OOM
```

table data:

```
name
---
ABI
TRE
BBR
DPR
OOM
RAM
```

query result will be:

```
name
---
RAM
DPR
OOM
ABI
BBR
TRE
```

I dont know how to begin the query except:

```
select name from tab order by ....
```

Comment: I'd make this two queries and union them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditions in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when name in ('RAM', 'DPR', 'OOM') then 0 else 1 end),
         name
```

If you want the list in a particular order:

```
order by (case when name = 'RAM' then 1
               when name = 'DPR' then 2
               when name = 'OOM' then 3
               else 4
          end), name
```